# How do I change the database engine for a database instance?

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-rds

I want to switch from mysql to postgres. I cant find that option anywhere.

If that is not possible, how do I decommision this instance? I cant find that option either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the engine once created. For decommision, you can use You can follow the instruction [on this page](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/96057.htm)